# jQuery element is not removing

Tags: jquery, html

I want to remove element where `id=decoratives / Interior` but it not working.

If it is not working because special character then how can I change `/` with whitespace?

```js
$(".remove").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var category = $(this).data("cat");
  $('#' + category.replace(/\s/g, '')).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="decoratives/Interior">
  <a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">
      <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <a class="remove" data-cat="decoratives / Interior">Remove Image</a> 

</div>
```

Comment: And what's the value of `category`?!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder decoratives / Interior

Comment: @ShahRushabh I took the liberty to update your question with a (non-)working snippet to give the example to fix

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for editing this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [attribute  equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) since itcotains meta-character `/`.

```
$('[id="' + category.replace(/\s/g,'') + '"]').remove();
```

```js
$(".remove").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var category = $(this).data("cat");
  $('[id="' + category.replace(/\s/g, '') + '"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="decoratives/Interior">
  <a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">
      <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <a class="remove" data-cat="decoratives / Interior">Remove Image</a> 

</div>
```

---

or you need to escape meta-character `/` by `\\/`.

```
$('#' + category.replace(/\s/g,'').replace('/','\\/')).remove();
```

```js
$(".remove").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var category = $(this).data("cat");
  $('#' + category.replace(/\s/g, '').replace('/', '\\/')).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="decoratives/Interior">
  <a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">
      <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <a class="remove" data-cat="decoratives / Interior">Remove Image</a> 

</div>
```

From [jQuery Selectors docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  ``` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`` {|}~ ``` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\.` For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Comment: @ShahRushabh :  glad to help  you :)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a character like `/` in an `id`, you can't use a CSS ID selector to get the element without escaping the `/`, which is a pain.

Your options not involving escaping the `/` are to use an attribute selector:

```
$('[id="' + category.replace(/\s/g, '') + '"]').remove();
```

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var category = "decoratives/Interior";
  $('[id="' + category.replace(/\s/g, '') + '"]').remove();
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="decoratives/Interior">
  <a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">
      <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <a class="remove" data-cat="decoratives / Interior">Remove Image</a> 

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or `getElementById`:

```
$(document.getElementById(category.replace(/\s/g, '')).remove();
```

Example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var category = "decoratives/Interior";
  $(document.getElementById(category.replace(/\s/g, ''))).remove();
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="decoratives/Interior">
  <a class="fancybox-gallery" href="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg">
    <img class="animate scale animated" src="http://wallpapercraze.com/images/wallpapers/nowallpaper-585747.jpeg" alt="Image1" style="height:75px">
    <div class="image-hover">
      <i class="icon-zoom-in-2"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <a class="remove" data-cat="decoratives / Interior">Remove Image</a> 

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```